# Bug when exporting multiples .fbx in a loop via Python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, export, .fbx

*see the Python script at the end*

I have a folder of .fbx files sitting on my computer. I want to import those files in Blender (I am using Blender 4.0.2), perform a few modifications on the animation trajectory data, and then export back the modified version in .fbx format. I want it done automatically via Python scripting.

My current Python script loops over the .fbx folder, imports the files, computes the number of keyframes in the animation (it will do more than that in the future but I kept it simple for the sake of clarity here), and then exports back the data.

The code runs well, but the exported .fbx files, even though they have different names, contain exactly the same data. It seems like it corresponds to the data from first imported .fbx file (from first loop passage). In other words, Blender exports the same data 3 times under 3 different names and I don't understand why.

If I break the loop, and import/export the files one by one by manually setting 'fname' to 'fbx_files[0]', 'fbx_files[1]' etc., the exported files are correct (this is why I'm guessing it has something to do with the for loop)

I've tried pretty much all possible parameters for 'bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx' function but nothing seems to solve my issue.

As you can see in the code, I also tried deleting imported object at the end of the loop to prevent from possible clash issues when calling objects during next loop iteration.

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong ? I'm not that comfortable with Blender and Python so I hope I am not missing something obvious here.

Here's my script :

```
import bpy, os, re, math, sys

folder_path = 'C:\\MY\\PATH\\IN'
folder_path_out = 'C:\\MY\\PATH\\OUT'

file_extension = ".fbx"

# Extract offset from .fbx filename (explained in details later)
def extract_last_number(file_name):
    match = re.search(r'\d+', file_name[::-1])
    if match:
        return match.group()[::-1]
    else:
        return None

# Get list of all the files in the folder
all_files = os.listdir(folder_path)

# Filter the files to include only those with the specified extension
fbx_files = [file for file in all_files if file.lower().endswith(file_extension)]

# Number of files in the folder
number_of_files = len(fbx_files)

# Counter
counter = 1

for fnames in fbx_files:

    print(f"\nProcessing file {counter} of {number_of_files}")

    print("Import '" + fnames + "' into Blender")

    # Specify the file path to the currently processed FBX file
    fbx_filepath = folder_path + '\\' + fnames

    # .fbx files are exported from UE5
    # For some reason, keyframes numbering is different for UE5, and they come with an offset
    # I always indicate this offset in filename when exporting from UE5 so I just need to read it
    # and set the correct parameter later when I import the file
    offset = -1*float(extract_last_number(fnames))

    print("Applied offset: ", end='')
    print(int(offset))

    # Import the FBX file
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_filepath, use_anim=True, anim_offset=offset)

    print("Checking start/end offset")

    # Get the active collections
    active_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection

    # Get object name
    object_name = active_collection.objects[0].name

    # Get camera object
    OBJECT = bpy.data.objects[object_name]

    # Get framerange
    # Find the first keyframe in the scene
    first_keyframe = None

    if OBJECT.animation_data is not None and OBJECT.animation_data.action is not None:
        keyframes = [f for f in OBJECT.animation_data.action.frame_range]
        if keyframes:
            first_keyframe = int(min(keyframes))
            last_keyframe = int(max(keyframes))
            str_kf = 'Keyframes range: ' + '(' + str(first_keyframe) + ', ' +                         
str(last_keyframe) + ')'
            print(str_kf)
        
    # Set first and last keyframe
    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = first_keyframe
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = last_keyframe
        
    # Update to apply changes
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

    framerange = range(first_keyframe, last_keyframe + 1)

    # Number of keyframes in animation
    nb_of_keyframes = last_keyframe - first_keyframe

    print("Exporting .fbx")

    # Output filepath
    fbx_filepath_output = folder_path_out + '\\AS_' + fnames

    # Clear the existing selection
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # Get camera object by name
    camera_object = bpy.data.objects.get(object_name)

    # Select the object by name
    bpy.data.objects[object_name].select_set(True)

    # Export .fbx
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
    filepath=fbx_filepath_output,
    use_selection=True,
    object_types={'CAMERA'},
    bake_anim=True,
    bake_anim_simplify_factor=0.)

    print(f"FBX file exported to: {fbx_filepath_output}")

    # Deselect all objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # Select the only object in the active collection
    if active_collection.objects:
        active_collection.objects[0].select_set(True)

    #Delete the selected objects
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    counter += 1

print("\nFinished processing files")
```